# Change value of column if value exists in list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a R dataframe that is structured like this :

```
indx <- as.factor(c('A01','A02','A03','B01','B02','B03'))
data <- runif(6,0,10)
valid <- rep(TRUE, 6)

df <- data.frame(indx, data, valid)

  indx     data valid
1  A01 6.534581  TRUE
2  A02 4.996695  TRUE
3  A03 3.328804  TRUE
4  B01 2.342048  TRUE
5  B02 9.928362  TRUE
6  B03 5.484037  TRUE
```

I also have a list of `indx` values when are not valid.

```
invalid_list <- as.factor(c('A02','B03'))
```

How can I change the value of `valid` to be `FALSE` if the `indx` exists in the `invalid_list`?

Result should look like this :

```
  indx     data valid
1  A01 6.534581  TRUE
2  A02 4.996695  FALSE
3  A03 3.328804  TRUE
4  B01 2.342048  TRUE
5  B02 9.928362  TRUE
6  B03 5.484037  FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `%in%` and assign the matching ones  to `FALSE` in 'valid'

```
df$valid[df$indx %in%invalid_list] <- FALSE
```

Comment: +1 because this is more readable, but could also negate and assign the condition directly using `df$valid <- !df$indx %in% invalid_list`.

Comment: @LMc thanks, I was thinking about that, but the OP already created a column 'valid'  So I used the assignment

Answer (score 2):

A solution based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(valid = ifelse(indx %in% invalid_list, FALSE, valid))
```

Comment: This works nicely too .. the readability of @akrun answer is very straight forward.  This may actually work best in my implementation since I'm working with `dplyr` and have a line creating the valid column already.  Modifying the else condition to `TRUE` in this case does everything in one line.  Great answers all around.  The big missing piece for me was `%in%`

Comment: Glad to hear that, @agf1997! I have learned a lot from @akrun brilliant answers!